# Limit to single decimal point

Tags: ios

I'm writing an iPhone app where the user is requested to input decimal a value. I would like to limit user to inputing a single decimal place. i.e. stopping the user entering something meaningless like 10.10.2.

Any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance.

R

Comment: Have you considered using a [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) instead? This would make your expected input more obvious to the user, and also a lot easier than using a keypad.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad
So the User can only enter Numbers and only one decimal point!

http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/13/iphone-number-pad-with-a-decimal-point/

Comment: I am using the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad however I'm not sure how to limit to a single decimal point. DevedUps solution is good but I'd prefer to use UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad.

Comment: Are we talking about an "." or an decimal place?